# Is there a way to estimate the number of R users?

Tags: r

I have found many websites presenting various data related to R: number of  packages downloads, number of conferences, number of queries and so on. As far as I recall, in 2013 Oracle estimated the number of R users to 2 000 000 people:

> There are now about 2 million R users worldwide who utilize thousands
>   of open sources packages within the R ecosystem
>   [Source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-analytics/r-enterprise/bringing-r-to-the-enterprise-1956618.pdf)

but it seems they just counted number of downloads of packages (but how? Just added them even if many were downloaded by a single user?), not downloads of R itself.

It is easy to count users of commercial programs like SAS or Office, because one has to register somehow and then he gets a "serial ID". Even if few users hold more than licence, counting them is still a good approximation.

But how to do that in context of R? Do you know any methods, sources, publications touching this problem?

Comment: I didn't give a down vote, but I suspect the down vote is because this question in outside the scope of stackoverflow. This site is intended to address in programming issues.